# how to sum in subquery in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

i want to sum in addselect() function but it show me error.
I have 2 model as see there:

1.jewelItem model:

```
protected $table = 'jewel_items';

public function buyInvoice(){
    return $this->belongsTo(BuyInvoice::class,'buy_invoice_id');
}
```

2.buyInvoice model:

```
protected $table = 'buy_invoices';

public function jewelsItems(){
return $this->hasMany(JewelsItems::class);
}
```

and every jewelItem has weight column.
my query:

```
  $buyInvoice=BuyInvoice::addSelect(['allWeight'=>JewelsItem::whereColumn('buy_invoices.id','buy_invoice_id')->sum('weight')
        ])->get();
```

but it show me this error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'buy_invoices.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select sum(`weight`) as aggregate from `jewel_items` where `buy_invoices`.`id` = `buy_invoice_id`)
```

how can i fix this without using Raw method, cause as [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-methods) says "Raw statements will be injected into the query as strings" and it's vulnerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In newer version of laravel you can use [`withSum`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions) to get sum of weights for related `jewelsItems`

```
$buyInvoice=BuyInvoice::withSum('jewelsItems', 'weight')
                      ->orderBy('jewelsItems_sum_weight')
                      ->get();
```

Or in older versions you could use `withCount` for sum as

```
 $buyInvoice= BuyInvoice::withCount([
                            'jewelsItems as allWeight' => function ($query) {
                                        $query->select(DB::raw("sum(weight)"));
                            }
                    ])->orderBy('allWeight')
                      ->get();
```

Comment: I got a new error:    Call to undefined method App\Models\BuyInvoice::withSum()

Comment: @yassin So you are using older version then try the second approach withCount

Comment: but my dude. my laravel framwork version is 8.0.0 so is it old? and as i said i don't want to use raw method cause of it's vulnerable

Answer (score 0):

you forgot use join in this subquery

```
JewelsItem::whereColumn('buy_invoices.id','buy_invoice_id')->sum('weight')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a custom count subquery, `Laravel` has syntaxic sugar for doing this, utilizing the method `withSum()`. An example of that could be.

```
$data = Model::query()->withSum('relation.subRelation','weight')->get();
```